# How to customize ant design calendar height cell

Tags: css, calendar, antd

I am currently getting an issue with `ant design calender`. As I want to show full content in cells, so I set the height for the `div` inside `td` tag to `auto`, then it works as expected. But its siblings(div in the same row which has no content) not showing full height. Here is the current behavior:
[image]

and here is what I expected it will be:
[image]

so how can I customize the css to get the div(which has empty content in the same row with the cell that has content) full height?
Here is the code:

```
<table class="ant-picker-content">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>日</th>
      <th>月</th>
      <th>火</th>
      <th>水</th>
      <th>木</th>
      <th>金</th>
      <th>土</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td title="2020-11-29" class="ant-picker-cell">
        <div class="ant-picker-cell-inner ant-picker-calendar-date"><!-- the div I expted to customize css -->
          ...empty
        </div>
      </td>
      <td title="2020-11-29" class="ant-picker-cell">
        <div class="ant-picker-cell-inner ant-picker-calendar-date">
          ...has content
        </div>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please create a demo using Codesandbox.